# "Could not find the dialect in the configuration" Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent Nhibernate with MSSql 2008 in an ASP.net MVC 3.0 project.

```
 
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
 FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
     .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
       .ConnectionString("Data Source=Comp;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=true")
       .ShowSql()).ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperties(AddProperty()))
     .Mappings(m => m
       .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf());
       return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}

private static IDictionary  AddProperty()
        {
            IDictionary config = new Dictionary();
            config.Add("current_session_context_class", "web");
            config.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle");
            return config;
        }
```

But, I am getting this error "Could not find the dialect in the configuration"

Answer (score 2):

You are actually overwriting all the properties that have been set by all previous configuration steps. Try adding to the collection instead:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
            .ConnectionString("Data Source=Comp;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=true")
            .ShowSql())
        .ExposeConfiguration(AddProperties)
        .Mappings(m => m
            .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf());

    return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}

private static IDictionary  AddProperties(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config)
{
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "web");
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle");
    return config;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                            .ConnectionString("Data Source=Comp;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=true")
                            .ShowSql().Dialect("NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect")).ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperties(AddProperty()))
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf());
```

Also for the WebSessionContext, you could use this code

```
FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()
                            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                            .ConnectionString("Data Source=Comp;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=true").CurrentSessionContext<WebSessionContext>()
                            .ShowSql().Dialect("NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect"))
```

Comment: MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008 - this initializes the dialect

Comment: Yes, this works simply and is simple enough. You can even change the connection string to: .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DefaultConnection")) and pull it from the web.config file.